# "new ArrayAdapter<String>(this " error when used in dialog null exception

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, android-dialog

hi, I have been working on a dialog box and i need a ListView inside the dialog box. The problem is i cant use "this" "new ArrayAdapter(this"

Can someone help me?

```
ListView dialog_ListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, comment11);

dialog_ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What is the error? Could it be that this block is inside an anonymous inner class?

Comment: many thanks for quick message , this code is inside  SlidingDrawer which is inside dialog box

Comment: Well,  `this` would be a dialog context, not an activity context.  Use `getActivity()' and things should go better.

Comment: getActivity() does not work , it gives error :(

Comment: or instead of `this` use `MyActivity.this`

Comment: i tried getBaseContext()  does not work :(

Comment: MyActivity.this does not work as well

Comment: when i put "this" it shows error "The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new SlidingDrawer.OnDrawerOpenListener(){}, int, String[]) is 
 undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this workaround helps you:

```
ListView dialog_ListView = (ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(dialog_ListView.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, comment11);

dialog_ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```